# Disable animation on image recognition with Wikitude SDK 3.0

Tags: android, sdk, z-index, image-recognition, wikitude

I'm integrating a modified SDK 3.0 sample into a big app in which I'm working.

When I detect whatever Trackable2DObject and show an ImageDrawable (for example, the surf table), this ImageDrawable appears from the z-index very slowly.

Is there any way to disable this animation?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: My JS code only contains this:

```
var World = {

loaded: false,

init: function initFn() {
this.createOverlays();
},

createOverlays: function createOverlaysFn() {
// Initialize Tracker
this.tracker = new AR.Tracker("assets/wul4bus.wtc", {
onLoaded: this.worldLoaded
});

// Create overlay for page one
var imgOne = new AR.ImageResource("assets/redsys_marker_orange.png");
var overlayOne = new AR.ImageDrawable(imgOne, 0.5, {
   zorder: 0,
offsetX: -0.15,
offsetY: 0,
onClick: this.createClickTrigger
});

   var titleLabel = new AR.Label("Bus", 0.07, {
               zOrder: 1,
               offsetX: -0.15,
               offsetY: 0.04,
               style: {
                   textColor: '#FFFFFF',
                   fontStyle: AR.CONST.FONT_STYLE.BOLD
               }
           });

var pageOne = new AR.Trackable2DObject(this.tracker, "002", {
drawables: {
cam: [overlayOne, titleLabel]
}
});
},

createClickTrigger: function createClickTriggerFn() {
   document.location = "architectsdk://product?id=1236";
},

worldLoaded: function worldLoadedFn() {
document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('loadingMessage'));
}
};

World.init();
```

As you see, there is no AR.PropertyAnimation class along this code. Anyway, a small animation succedeed *sometimes* when the target is discovered, and trackable object appears a bit slowly, slower than SDK 2 IMHO. It happens with some Trackable2DObject more than others.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the [API Reference of the Wikitude SDK](http://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/3.0/Reference/JavaScript%20Reference/index.html).
You will find details around Animations there.
If you need a Sample collection and platform specific stuff, have a look at the [Wikitude Documentation page](http://developer.wikitude.com/documentation).

Kind regards,
Andreas

Comment: I've edited my question. It's not about how to make animations, it's more about the performance when trackable objects are detected.